# ArangoDB - update vs. replace

Tags: arangodb

I'm curious about the difference (except the obvious one) between update and replace of a document within ArangoDB.

When is it best to use update, and when is it best to use replace?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use whatever is best for you to modify your documents. There should be little to no difference in performance, because new document revisions are written either way (append only principle).

Just make sure you don't unset a lot of attributes and replace the document by accident instead of updating a few attributes only.

Comment: thanks! that's what I thought but wanted to double-check

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference. If your collection has a Array/List/Dictionary etc, updating will not remove values, you need to replace it.